# Using thread in loop

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a loop as shown below

```
while (something)
{
     System.Threading.Thread newthread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => CreatePDF(strPDFHTML, filePath));
     newthread.Start();

     Console.WriteLine("Creating PDF.");
}
```

When I create a new `Thread` object and place it in `newthread` as I do in the loop... in the second iteration of the loop, is the previous running thread overwritten/interrupted? What issues will arise (if any)?

Comment: No and maybe. Depends on what `CreatePDF` is doing and how many of these threads you are firing off at once.

Comment: What does "overwrite a thread" mean to you?

Comment: CreatePDF takes about a second or 2...

Comment: By overwrite a thread i mean the previous thread is stopped in between and replaced by this new thread

Comment: @Suresh ok I understand. You should probably make yourself familiar with how reference types and variables work in C#. Overwriting a reference never influences the referenced object in any way.

Answer (score 3):

> [...] is the previous running thread overwritten

Actually it's not overwritten: you are creating a new reference in each iteration.

It should be no problem, unless you want to manage the threads you're creating during the whole loop (for example, how would you manage to end some thread?).

In the other hand, I would take a look at [`TaskFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782519%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx).

Comment: `for example, how would you abort one thread?` You wouldn't, because aborting threads is pure evil and you shouldn't attempt to do so.

Comment: @Servy I know, but you know what I want to communicate in my answer: you want to have control over the threads you're launching. Evil or not, once a thread is launched you won't be able to cancel it. When I said "abort" I wasn't speaking about `Thread.Abort`. Keep calm!!

Comment: That comment was half in jest.  While you shouldn't be aborting threads, and I do think that's a poor example to use, the point you're trying to make is clear, and unrelated.  Don't freak out.

Comment: @Servy I've received several comments from you in some questions and/or answers, and I feel you're not always trying to add value to my contribution. When I see "Servy" on my inbox I know it'll be a "definitive and irrefutable information". This is how a freaking word destroys an answer (from your point of view). Anyway, I've replaced "abort" with "manage to end". Maybe I was absolutely wrong and now the abstract message within my answer has changed a lot (irony!).

Answer (score 2):

The handle to the thread is lost, but the thread itself will continue to run until it finishes. You will not be able to determine when the thread has finished, unless you have some internal communication in place.

Answer (score 2):

If we logically walk through your program we can figure out exactly what is going on.

1. Create a place in memory to store a `Thread` object, we will call him `newThread`

   ```
   System.Threading.Thread newthread
   ```
2. You create a new instance of a `Thread` object and place a refrence to it in the `newThread` variable.

   ```
   newthread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => CreatePDF(strPDFHTML, filePath));
   ```
3. You look at the pointer in `newThread`, and follow it to a `Thread` object, and you call the `Start()` method on that thread.

   ```
   newthread.Start();
   ```
4. The loop ends, and we loose the variable `newThread`, but `newThread` was just a pointer to the real object, so the thread continues to run in the background, while then we repeat this process.

   ```
   }
   ```

In this example you don't need to even create the memory handle `newThread`. You are storing the pointer to be used once more later. When you create the object to begin with you also have a pointer to this object, so you might as-well call start on the object in the beginning, and not bother to hold the reference to the thread.

```
new System.Threading.Thread(() => CreatePDF(strPDFHTML, filePath)).Start();
```

Above I simply created the Thread object and called start on it. it will function exactly the same as your code. It will however not bother to make the thread handle your were losing right away anyway.

Comment: Thanks Ben it is nicely Explained

Answer (score 0):

While (something) is creating threads the whole time i think the second thread will have a problem becuase the file might been used from other threads. USE TASKS factory and wait when you need wait all I will update the answer how can you that with Task.

---

```
    // I prefer here to use ManualResetEvent better then while or while with timeout
    while(something)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            CreatePDF(strPDFHTML, filePath)
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning); // this way you do not need sleep
    }
```

You can do something Task.WaitAll() or and you can add a cancel token in case of cancellation is required; You can get also the AggreateException in main thread this will help you to find where was the problem et.c

Comment: ...? It's not wrong at all. It depends on how CreatePDF writes to the file system. And what if it writes to a memory stream?

Comment: Or, what if it has thread synchronization (i.e monitor, readerwriterlockslim....) so it can't write 1 file at once!!

Comment: CreatePDF both are wrong when wrting to file you will get access problem when it writng to memory you will get a memory exception later . You donot know whole long this while(something) is alive; This is a code smell .NET offer a lot of new tech to solve like those problem

Comment: As such there wont be any problem in Creating PDF because each CreatePDF call saves the PDF with a different Name. My code running absolutely fine now..i m worried about how it will work when data is heavy...

Comment: @BassamAlugili Argue whatever: I believe your answer is absolutely wrong and it doesn't answer OP's question....

Comment: @Suresh your code is very CPU heavy also when you are doing some sleeps you are killing. I donot know if you want to keep it like that? or you want also to improve it then i can help u

Comment: Ya any help will definately be great to improve